# Rebasing a pull request

Tags: mysql, git, github, travis-ci

I initiated a [pull request](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/1044). After back and forth, we had agreed on the changes and all tests had passed. I was asked to reduce the commit history to two commits.  So I rebased on my local branch, and push it to origin. I used the `--force-with-lease` option for safety.

On my github fork, all Travis tests passed, but on the PR, every test failed when the following command was [executed](https://travis-ci.org/activerecord-hackery/ransack/jobs/564507157)

```
mysql -e 'create database ransack collate utf8_general_ci;
```

with the following error message

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
The command "mysql -e 'create database ransack collate utf8_general_ci;'" failed and exited with 1 during
```

I also received an email from github pointing me to an [error message](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/1044/files/7068c7b3975c8d8bb31c4936c17f100edc348bee..85fc715a16f54620d54094c6e5f9f1ccc92b67f2) saying that the commit had dissappeared.

What has caused this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Could the [change](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/1044/files) to `.travis.yml` cause it?

Comment: Did you try to manually re-execute the build?

Comment: I dont think so, partly because the error is happening in the before_script, i.e. before the changes, those changes were not causing a problem when being pushed before, and the CI tests are working on my forked repository,https://github.com/obromios/ransack/commits/fix_for_%231042, and it was the push to the forked repository that caused the CI tests to start on the PR.

Comment: @maroun, yes, the next day I closed the PR and then reopened, and the build started again with same result.

Comment: I closed the PR and started a new one, and am getting the same problem.  The branch was just pushed, not force pushed, it is not a rebasing issue.  Also, now I am see the same build errors on my fork.  I notice that  there has been a similar issue with travis-ci before: (https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6842).  I will investigate further.